# Strange issue using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using thread to start a public function of a class. The problem is that only if set break point inside the  thread function(public function of the class) it gets called otherwise calling the Thread.Start is not having any effect. Once the thread function is called it is completing successfully giving desired results.

```
 QueueProcessor     processor  = null;
 Thread subprocess =null;

 public void processQueue()
 {
    if (processor == null)
    {         
        processor = new QueueProcessor();
    }

    if (subprocess == null)
    {                                            
        subprocess = new Thread(processor.run);
        subprocess.IsBackground = true;
    }

    if (!subprocess.IsAlive)
    {                
        subprocess.Start();                                
    }
    else
    {          
    }
} 

class QueueProcessor
{       
    public QueueProcessor()
    {           
        instance = new RecordDao();
        service = new CommonsService();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        startProcessing(); // it won't reach here unless a breakpoint is set.
    }

    public bool startProcessing()
    {
        //some database routines here.

       // some web service calls here
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: `THIS IS ALWAYS FALSE IN SOME CASES` ???

Comment: Actually, "Always false in some cases" makes sense to me - in some test runs, `subProcess.IsAlive` remains false forever; in other test runs it's *sometimes* false.

Comment: Why do you think that code does not execute? You do very little work in your thread. Are you sure it has not completed before your IsAlive-check?

Comment: Sorry guys removed Always false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Now that you've changed the code, there are two problems:

1. You potentially try to *restart* a thread, if you ever call `processQueue` after the processing has finished. You can't do that.
2. If `processQueue` is called from multiple threads, you have issues of potentially starting multiple threads due to race conditions, and also memory model potential issues.

The first point is more simply solved using:

```
if (subprocess == null || !subprocess.IsAlive)
{                                            
    subprocess = new Thread(processor.run);
    subprocess.IsBackground = true;
    subprocess.Start();
}
```

... but this still leaves the potential problem of the second point. What is calling `processQueue`? Is it always the same thread? (And why are you ignoring .NET naming conventions?)

My guess is that what you're seeing is *actually* the processing happening exactly once, but there being no work to do, and future calls not restarting the thread as presumably you expected - whereas if you have the breakpoint there, then by the time you hit "go" again, there's work to do. At a guess... certainly starting a thread *does* work without breakpoints, so the flaw is somewhere in your code. If you could produce a short but *complete* program that demonstrates the problem, we could get to the bottom of it.

---

Your thread does almost nothing, so it's entirely reasonable for the thread to complete before it reaches the `while` loop. It's not that it doesn't start - it's that it starts and then finishes immediately.

Alternatively, you could have an execution flow like this:

```
Main thread                  New thread status

                             Not started...

Check: IsAlive == false

                             Still not started...

Check: IsAlive == false

                             Starting!
                             Call startProcessing...
                             startProcessing completes...
                             Finished

Check: IsAlive == false
```

The thread has executed with no problems, but `IsAlive` is always false.

It's not clear *why* you have this code in the first place - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Right. The thread isn't 'alive' yet when the property is checked.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive: Not alive *yet*, or not alive *any more*. There's no difference as far as the `IsAlive` property is concerned.

Comment: In fact the thread function do some complex database function and web service calls. I did not posted it here since it contains lot of external dependencies. Never thought of this loophole. Updated the code by adding comment //some database routines here.

Comment: Updated the code to remove the IsAlive checking..Looks like it is creating confusion here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that processor.run matches the signature for the thread parameter but its not right, so the thread never gets a valid function, so it never starts.  The function that the thread runs should be a static function, and in this case I would move the thread in to the processing classes object.

Comment: but it calls the same thread function in  cases when i set break point . Thanks

Comment: In your example code, on my machine it never calls it.  You sure something else isn't calling it?  Maybe your working on a project and the example is quite the same as the project?

Comment: No,It is called only from one location.Thanks